# SLIME: How to use the result from the repl as plain text?

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, slime

After slime prints a Lisp form in REPL it puts some properties on it, that make it later able to introspect / expand it etc. Some times it is very useful, but other times I'd like to re-use the result as just text.

What is the quick way to remove this special property from a form?

Comment: `substring-no-properties`?

Comment: @abo-abo this is kind of long... I could also select region and then `M-x facemenu-removal-all`, but I thought there was some SLIME-related way (it must also GC the object connected to that text).

Comment: You mean like * in `ielm`?

Comment: @VsevolodDyomkin doesn't work for me :( I have an object, that defines `print-object` to be printed as a list, but when I want to use what was printed as if it was a list, I still get my underlying object instead of list.

Comment: @abo-abo there's not such problem with Emacs Lisp because you cannot define a custom printing function (or so I think).

Comment: @RainerJoswig yes, this worked, thanks! You can make it an answer if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just print the last output to a string:

`(princ-to-string *)`

To expand a bit: SLIME implements something like *presentations*, which were introduced by Symbolics for its Dynamic Windows user interface. Presentations of Lisp objects can be in various forms: textual and graphical. They always remember the original objects - which makes them clickable/active. With Dynamic Windows you could also select a textual presentation and copy the output as a text to the editor killring. I would guess that SLIME/Emacs can do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can just right click on the presentation and choose Pretty-print, or move point to the presentation and invoke `M-x slime-pretty-print-representation-at-point`. This will pretty print the presentation in another buffer.